# Pagination in WordPress blog for pages posts

Tags: php, wordpress

Added this piece of code to show all the pages below the posts on the blog homepage by adding this in the index.php.

```
<!-- Start page loop here -->
<?php $query = new wp_query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => '3' ) ); ?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ): while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
<!-- Start page template here -->
<div><a aria-label="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
<!-- End page template here -->
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<!-- End page loop here -->
```

For Pagination, this piece of code is already there by default in the twenty-twenty WordPress theme.

```
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/pagination' ); ?>
```

But the problem is pagination is only applied to the blog posts articles, But not on the page's articles on the blog homepage.

There are a total of 100 blog posts and 100 pages post.

The blog has 5 blog posts and 5 pages posts on the homepage. When going to 2nd page of the blog using pagination, the other 5 blog posts are rendered, but pages posts are rendered the same as on the first page.

How it is possible to change the page's posts(Same as blog posts) using the same pagination used for blog posts?

I have tried to resolve this problem but not able to find any solution to this.

I hope the problem is clear. Looking for a solution. Thanks

Comment: That’s just not how pages work. You will have to custom code all that functionality into WP. If that’s what you want to do, why not use posts in the first place, which work the way you want?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. This is a very rare case. Actually we published many pages along with the posts 4-5 years back. At that time we were not having much knowledge of using WordPress. Now, we cannot changes the URL as we get good traffic from them and want them to be displayed on our homepage for better SEO. I hope you understood the scenario.

Comment: I understand now why you are trying to do this. Its still a lot of work to re-engineer the default behaviour of WP though My suggestion is to recreate those pages as blog posts and use 301 redirects in htaccess to redirect the old URLs to the new ones. This will work for both visitors & search engines, and importantly **301 redirects don't affect SEO** - they simply pass on PageRank info to the new URL. If you do take this route, a word of advice is to set them up as 302 (temporary) redirects first until you test them... it takes time to recover from a mistake in a 301 (permanent) redirect!